# Find SVG element with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

`if( element.find( 'text[data-color], path[data-color], rect[data-color], line[data-color], circle[data-color], polygon[data-color], ellipse[data-color], polyline[data-color]' ).attr( 'data-color' ) == color)`

What is a prettier/better way to write that?

Comment: Do you really care about the tag name?

Comment: Yes, could be any of those, but definitely one of them.

Comment: The point is: Are there other tags that have `data-color` that you want to ignore? E.g., do you have (say) `marker` with `data-color` and you intentionally want to skip it?

Comment: Hmm, neh. Need to look at each of those and find which one has the value.

Comment: Apologies, but you don't seem to be understanding me. Do you have *other* elements in the SVG graph that **also** have `data-color` on them that you want to ignore? Because if not, `'[data-color]'` alone is all you need (as I say in my answer). It's **only** if you have other tags than the ones you've listed **and** they have `data-color` that it wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Yes, other elements may have that attribute and they need to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve readability a bit if you store tags in say array:

```
const selector = [
  'text',
  'path',
  'rect',
  'line',
  'circle',
  'polygon',
  'ellipse',
  'polyline'
].map(tag => `${tag}[data-color]`)

if (element.find(selector).attr('data-color') === color) {}
```